# Exiting from virtual terminal and automatically going back to X disables keyboard and mouse

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, mouse, systemd, virtual-console

When exiting from virtual terminal with automatic switch back to X the keyboard and mouse does not work any more.

Here is the sequence to reproduce the issue.

Hint: tty1 and tty2 are used by X for display manager and gnome session.

1. Ctrl + Alt + F3 to switch from X to virtual terminal tty3
2. Login
3. Exit (switching back to X is performed automatically)
4. Result: keyboard/mouse does not work any more

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I observed similar issue with my Ubuntu 18.04 laptop.

I changed to virtual terminal using the following command from Ubuntu Terminal:
`sudo chvt 2`

Then I logged in to my virtual terminal using my credentials and if I logout from virtual terminal, my Keyboard no longer works.

This was resolved by using the following command to come out of virtual terminal:
`sudo chvt 1`

In Ubuntu 18.04, the GNOME/GUI runs on virtual terminal 1, so switching back to virtual terminal 1 restored the GUI for me.

Hope this helps for you as well. Thanks

Comment: Good to know. But it does not help much. chvt 2 does the same as STRG+ALT+F2 and chvt 1 does the same as STRG+ALT+F1. Switching between virtual terminals is already working well.But the problem occurs on logout when switching automatically back to VT1.

Comment: Thanks sjuk for correcting me.  Yes logout directly from Virtual terminal is resulting in hang of keyboard and sorry I don't know the cause or fix  for this issue.